# Trouble with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to forward

```
https://pinpoll.net/plugin/getPoll?category_id=27
```

to

```
https://pinpoll.com/plugin/getPoll?category_id=27
```

Also, any non-secure http://*.*.* should be forwarded to https://*pinpoll.com e.g.,

`http://pinpoll.net/Blog` to `https://pinpoll.com/Blog`
or

`http://pinpoll.com` to `https://pinpoll.com`

Rules should **not** affect any subdomains like https://dev.pinpoll.com but work with http://www.pinpoll.net being forwarded to https://pinpoll.net.

This is what my .htaccess looks like at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)pinpoll\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pinpoll.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)pinpoll\.at [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pinpoll.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)pinpoll\.us [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pinpoll.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)pinpoll\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pinpoll.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)pinpoll\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pinpoll.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"

    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 20 days"
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </FilesMatch>

</ifModule>

<IFModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesmatch "\.(js|css|html|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesmatch>
</IFModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|cache)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Example URL

```
http://pinpoll.net/plugin/getPoll?category_id=27
```

would become

```
https://pinpoll.com/index.php/getPoll?category_id=27
```

...which is almost what I want, but I'm losing /plugin/ that is being replaced with /index.php/ instead. The latter should be the case only if neither file (!-f) nor folder (!-d) exists, which isn't the case for the desired output being

```
https://pinpoll.com/plugin/getPoll?category_id=27
```

Any help/hint is highly appreciated!

Cheers, Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your rules and place this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Just below `RewriteEngine On` line and test in a new browser.

Also place this rule below other https redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64243/discussion-between-anubhava-and-tobias).